# Different data in ggplot (geom_point) graphically not comparable (point sizes)

Tags: r, ggplot2, size, point, geom-point

I would like to visualize several datasets with ggplot as a scatterplot. The problem is that the point sizes are not comparable. The point for 20 for exampe in plot 1 is larger than in plot 2.
The problem can be solved with the limits command. However, I would enlarge all points altogether. This is possible with the range command. However, the sizes of the points are then again not comparable. Is there a possibility to combine both commands or an alternative?

```
data <- data.frame (
  A = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"),
  B = c(0.5,1.5,20.3,10.5,22,3,8.5,5.5,8.8,12.5,14.6,2.4)
)

data2 <- data.frame (
  A = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"),
  B = c(0.2,2.5,40.4,20.5,22,3,14.9,5.5,8.8,18.8,33.6,2.4)
)

# not comparable
ggplot(data, aes(x=A, y=B)) + geom_point(data=data, aes(x=A, y=B, size= B))+
  ggtitle("plot 1")

ggplot(data2, aes(x=A, y=B)) + geom_point(data=data2, aes(x=A, y=B, size= B))+
ggtitle("plot 2")


# comparable, but small points
ggplot(data, aes(x=A, y=B)) + geom_point(data=data, aes(x=A, y=B, size= B))+
scale_size_continuous(limits =c(1,40))+
  ggtitle("plot 1 limits")

ggplot(data2, aes(x=A, y=B)) + geom_point(data=data, aes(x=A, y=B, size= B))+
  scale_size_continuous(limits =c(1,40))+
  ggtitle("plot 2 limits")


# bigger points, but not comparable
ggplot(data, aes(x=A, y=B)) + geom_point(data=data, aes(x=A, y=B, size= B))+
  scale_size_continuous(range =c(1,10))+
  ggtitle("plot 1 range")

ggplot(data2, aes(x=A, y=B)) + geom_point(data=data, aes(x=A, y=B, size= B))+
  scale_size_continuous(range =c(1,10))+
  ggtitle("plot 2 range")
```

Comment: You can combine `range` and `limits` parameters in `scale_size_continuous(range=c(1,10),limits=c(1,40))`, I think it is what you exactly need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine both limits and range within scale_continuous. Better, however, is to merge both data sets and use facets.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

data1 <- data.frame (
  A = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"),
  B = c(0.5,1.5,20.3,10.5,22,3,8.5,5.5,8.8,12.5,14.6,2.4)
)

data2 <- data.frame (
  A = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"),
  B = c(0.2,2.5,40.4,20.5,22,3,14.9,5.5,8.8,18.8,33.6,2.4)
)

ggplot(data1, aes(x=A, y=B)) + geom_point(aes(x=A, y=B, size= B))+
  scale_size_continuous(limits =c(1,40), range =c(1,10))+
  ggtitle("plot 1 limits") +
  
  ggplot(data2, aes(x=A, y=B)) + geom_point(aes(x=A, y=B, size= B))+
  scale_size_continuous(limits =c(1,40), range =c(1,10))+
  ggtitle("plot 2 limits")
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

```r
# or, more ggplot2-like
bind_rows(data1, data2, .id = "data") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=A, y=B)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=A, y=B, size= B)) +
  facet_grid(~data)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>